# Isaiah's addressing of King Ahaz as "House of David"

Tags: isaiah-yeshaya-the-book

In Isaiah 7, when Ahaz refuses to ask for a sign as instructed by Isaiah, why does the Prophet then address Ahaz by saying "O House of David" instead of Ahaz's name?

Is Isaiah no longer addressing Ahaz specifically and redirecting to a larger audience (House of David) because Ahaz refuses?

[Judaica Press - Yeshayahu - Chapter 7](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15938/jewish/Chapter-7.htm)

[Sefaria.org Tanakh - Isaiah - Chapter 7](https://www.sefaria.org/Isaiah.7?lang=bi)

Comment: "_[W]hy does the Prophet then address Ahaz by saying 'O House of David' instead of Ahaz's name_"? Maybe, it's for the reason Rashi gives in [7:2](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15938/jewish/Chapter-7.htm#v=2&showrashi=true) ([Hebrew original](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Isaiah.7.2?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en)), "[s]ince he was wicked, Scripture did not mention his name"?